Forwarding Ansible through aws ec2 instance-connect
I'm currently using ec2 instance-connect to connect on a bastion instance on the public side.
My setup is a bastion host with a public ip on which I can ssh from any external IP.
A private instance in a private subnet which can be accessed only by the bastion host.
I'd like to forward Ansible request through ssh to the private instances in order to have them execute a bunch of tasks.
So far I can manually ssh to the bastion, then ssh to the private instance, but I can't come up with a command to allow Ansible to forward properly.
So far I'm using this command:
ssh -i .secrets/secret-key.pem -o ProxyCommand='aws ec2-instance-connect open-tunnel --instance-id i-04011022cbfc124f6' user@i-09e745ed42f686fdb
But for some reason it just create an ssh connection to i-04011022cbfc124f6which is the public instance and doesn't forward to i-09e745ed42f686fdb which is the private one.
I'm confused if this is doable or not, it should be as I don't see any problem in term of network (since I can manually connect to the first instance then the second without issue).
